# How to call custom insert Query using JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to call custom insert Query using JPA in Spring Boot.

```java
@Repository
public interface eosRepo extends JpaRepository<EosthirdpartylabelsRequest, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(
      value = 
        "INSERT INTO public.documents_zpl(\\r\\n\" +\r\n" + 
        "                 \"    loc_id, order_nbr, sub_order_nbr, carton_id, doc_payload, dt_ent, tm_ent, program_ent, dt_chg, tm_chg, program_chg)\\r\\n\"\r\n" + 
        "                 + \"  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?",
         nativeQuery = true)
        void insertData(Integer locID, Integer OrderNum,Integer SubOrderNum,Integer CartonId,String CarrierLabel);
      }
```

How can I call this query in Controller.

Comment: What's your question? You can call insertData

Comment: You forgot to put `)` after `?,?,?`

Comment: @AbinashGhosh: thanks for editing the question. A couple of style tips if I may: (1) if an author is in the habit of adding "please-help-me" begging phrases, remove them - it's redundant, and technical writing is preferred here; (2) there is no need to embolden whole sentences, and it does not make things any easier to read. Apply bold formatting very sparingly, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

First use:

```
@Autowired
eosRepo eosRepo;
```

in your controller and then call `insertData`.

Answer (score 0):

In controller firstly do this

```
@Autowired
private eosRepo object_name;
```

and then you can call this method
`object_name.insertData`

And put ')' in your query which you have forgot.

Answer (score 0):

- "  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", you are forgot to give ')' and also call repo from controller use

```
@Autowired
private eosRepo theEosRepo;
```